# PHP_XLSXWriter library questions

Tags: php, excel

I have some question about the [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter):

(1) 
When I go to [example.php](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter/blob/master/example.php), I don't understand the below code:

```
$writer->writeToStdOut();
```

What is the code meaning?

(2) 
When I go to [example-cli-load.php](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter/blob/master/example-cli-load.php), I follow this code:

```
echo '#'.floor((memory_get_peak_usage())/1024/1024)."MB"."\n";
```

It shows **#0MB** in web page. Why?

(3)
What is the difference between the `writeSheetRow` and `writeSheet`?

(4)
What is the purpose of `writeSheetHeader` from the following code?

```
$header = array("string","string"); 
...
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet_name, $header, $suppress_header_row = true);`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) 
>   When I go to example.php, I don't understand the below code:
>
> $writer->writeToStdOut();
>
> What is the code meaning?

It means write the spreadsheet to standard output (the browser) rather than write it to a file on the server

> (3)
>   What is the difference between the writeSheetRow and writeSheet?

`writeSheetRow()` writes a single row at the end of the worksheet; writeSheet() writes all the rows in the array that you pass as the argument

> (4)
>   What is the purpose of writeSheetHeader from the following code?
>
> $header = array("string","string"); 
>   ...
>   $writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet_name, $header, $suppress_header_row = true);

`writeSheetHeader()` doesn't just write a header row, it also sets style for a column. Suppressing the header row still sets the column styling (to string in this case) but without writing an actual header row